# What is the significance of power core colors in Into the Breach?

Tags: into-the-breach

There are three different colors of power core in Into The Breach.  Green ones are tied to the pilot, but there are two others: the standard yellow one, and a gray one with a yellow outline.

If the yellow ones are standard found-or-purchased cores, what do the gray ones indicate?

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of the different colours?

Answer (score 6):

The grey colour with a yellow outline means that you can uninstall that power core.

When you install a power core, you have the ability to remove it from that mech and install it on a different mech in case you made a mistake. This grace period lasts until the next mission.